# What SQL Query can I use to determine which databases have been updated recently?

Tags: mysql

I'm working with an older system and looking to migrate it, but there are probably 100 or so databases for various tools and functions this department has used over the years. Obviously I need to focus on the ones that are in use currently, but is there an easy way to find out if that's the case?

I can use PHPMyAdmin to manually look, but, as I said, there's a lot of DBs.

Comment: Look at the firewall log files. Each database is available at a different host, port, or context in the URLs, when connecting to them. That should tell you which ones have been accessed, at least.

Comment: I have full DB access, but not access to the system logs on this machine. I'm hoping for a query or other feature of PHPmyadmin to solve this problem. Maybe something using the msyql db itself to script looking for new entries to tables in each db.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I posted too soon. Turns out there was a good answer out there after all:

```
select table_schema as database_name,
       table_name,
       update_time
from information_schema.tables tab
where update_time > (current_timestamp() - interval 30 day)
      and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      and table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'sys',
                               'performance_schema','mysql')
      -- and table_schema = 'your database name' 
order by update_time desc;
```

The above query without uncommenting the bit about "your database name" enumerated all tables for all dbs on my server and showed me exactly what's being used. It was clean, easy, and fast.

EDIT: Credit where credit is due: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/mysql/find-recently-modified-tables